# Tail recursive function in order to insert x before an element

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I have an assignement, that ask me to create a function in C in order to insert an arg x before the last 0 of a linked-list. I've tried everything and my last attempt feel like it should works. But either my logic is broken or my knowledge about pointers is terrible.

Let me try to explain, My assignement required to create a function which will take  2 arguments a Custom List, and x an int. It will use a sub function with an "out" parameter.

So what I did, I go to the end of this list, if I comme across a 0 I'll store its address in my out parameter (type : List).
When my list is empty I will either stack x at the end if no zero has been found or I will insert it at the address of my out parameter.

When I debug, I can see that the address has been correctly assigned, my "insert" has been correctly done (at least, in the "out" parameter) but when I check after the call it doesn't change the value of "l". It works when it come to insert at the end, but that's it.

the code

```
        if (value(*l) == 0) {
            *lastOcc = *l;  // Assign address of zéro

// i'll add back the question after the deadline to avoid trouble, but the answer was here
```

The main is simple I call the function with (&l, 5).

I hope i've been clear enough. Can you point out what I'm missing, I really want to understand why my logic is a failure right now.

Thanks for your help

Comment: FYI, using loops would be easier to code and objectively better (no stack overflow for long lists!). Showing how you're calling this function would be useful in the interests of a fully runnable [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: Is _recursion_ a required part of the assignment?

Comment: Yes we have 3 ver. of it to do, a "terminate" one (don't know how its sayed in english but the one which will do nothing after the call), a no terminated one and an iterative one. That's the last one I have to do.

I've edited my answer with a kind of codepen @ggorlen

Comment: @Alex return from the function! What if the inserted one will be come a new head?  - I see you hide pointers behind typedefs - a very bad habit

Comment: @0___________ If I make it the head I will have to stack back the previous values on the way back of the recursive no ? I can't imagine it otherwise and if I do that it mean that it will operate after the call, an that's against the rules for this exercises.
Not guilty of this fault, this part of the code was my teacher doing ahah

Comment: Tell him to do not do this.  And simly do not use that typedef

Comment: @Alex Thanks, although all code should be in the question itself. Links can disappear over time, and the purpose of the site is to provide a resource for future visitors with the same problem as you. Please read the [mcve] link--it provides important techniques that will help you solve your programming problems, beyond just making your posts on topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
*lastOcc = *l
```

The `lastOcc` that you are using is always the local variable that you created in `AddBeforeLastZero`:

```
List lastOcc = NULL;
```

You are using the indirection `*Liste` to overwrite the pointers in-place, but `lastOcc` is never part of the linked list, so overwriting its value has no effect.

What you want is this:

```
lastOcc = l
```

Now, you will be able to overwrite the head `l` or some `l->next`.

See https://ideone.com/Zo3f7e .

Comment: Thank you so much, it was painfully obvious what I did wrong... I'll avoid this mistake for the exam. Any way thanks, I'll hide the thread to avoid copy of the xode for the time being but I'll show it back after deadline